# Tomcat with Netty inside single application context

Tags: spring, tomcat, websocket, netty, reactor

I have a spring application using tomcat, I would like to run netty as a parallel web server and share the application context between the two, I connected the web flux starter together with the web, but only tomcat starts on the port specified in the properties.`@Configuration
class NettyConfiguration {

```
@Bean
fun nettyReactiveWebServerFactory(): NettyReactiveWebServerFactory {
    val webServerFactory = NettyReactiveWebServerFactory()
    webServerFactory.addServerCustomizers(EventLoopNettyCustomizer())
    return webServerFactory
}

private class EventLoopNettyCustomizer : NettyServerCustomizer {
    override fun apply(httpServer: HttpServer): HttpServer {
        val parentGroup: EventLoopGroup = NioEventLoopGroup()
        val childGroup: EventLoopGroup = NioEventLoopGroup()
        return httpServer.port(8084)
            .tcpConfiguration { tcpServer ->
                tcpServer
                    .bootstrap { serverBootstrap ->
                        serverBootstrap
                            .group(parentGroup, childGroup)
                            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel::class.java)
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebServerConfig {

    private final HttpHandler httpHandler;

    public CustomWebServerConfig(HttpHandler httpHandler) {
        this.httpHandler = httpHandler;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void customPortNettyWebServer() {
        var factory = new NettyReactiveWebServerFactory(8082);
        var webServer = factory.getWebServer(httpHandler);
        webServer.start();
    }
}
```